# Use a variable as the dimension of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dimension

I was just wondering why this works in Clang 4.0:

```
unsigned cnt = 42;
int k[cnt];
```

But this won't:

```
unsigned cnt = 42;
string bad[cnt];
```

I just checked C++ primer 5th edition. It says that:

> the dimension must be known at compile time, which means that the
>   dimension must be a constant expression

If that's true, why does the `int k[cnt];` work?

Comment: `const unsigned cnt = 42;`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I understand that I should use `const`. I was just wondering why `int k[cnt];` works but `string k[cnt]` doesn't.. Is it a historical issue inherited from `C`?

Comment: Don't do it. What you want is (of course) `std::vector<std::string>(42);`

Comment: In this case, even better than const would be constexpr.

Comment: Seems *clang* doesn't conform to C++ here, probably some extension porting over C99 VLA rubbish to C++ (which might be the reason why it won't work for non-trivial types).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neither snippet works in C++.

However, in C, it's possible to use non-constant expressions as array sizes. Some compilers (for example, GCC without `-pedantic` option) support that C feature in C++ code.

As for the difference between element types, it's compiler-specific. GCC compiles both. clang++ prohibits non-POD types (such as `std::string`) in this case.

Comment: C++11 does not support it. However, the feature is planned for C++14 or C++17. With some restrictions compared to C99/C11 though.

Comment: @Morwenn it's being considered (after all, it is existing practice for many C++ implementations), Stroustup is for it, as long as pointer type can be fixed (in C, pointer to an element of VLA is not compatible with pointer to an element of a regular array)

Comment: Yes. And they also consider not to port the run-time behaviour of `sizeof` if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler are you using, I am using gcc and both const and nonconst works fine.

It is not a matter of c, arrays are not meant to be defined through variables, only macros and const expressions.

It's a matter of compiler's interpretation, I doubt it is related to standards.

Answer (score 0):

Is clang 4.0 actually apple xcode clang? i think that is actually version 3.1. clang offers a nice explanation itself:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature
      [-Wvla-extension]
    int k[cnt];
```